# Whats the best way to draw and position div[square] around the div[rectangle]

Tags: javascript

I have different sized DIV elements. For ex, it can be a rectangle or a square. Rectangle can have either height is bigger than the width or vice-versa. What I want to achieve is, I want to draw a Square around those elements so that I can convert them to Circle using CSS. See the image

[image]

I have tried to get diagonal length and draw the required square. But I am failing to position it properly around the rectangle shaped DIV.

See the images below: I want to draw SQUARE around highlighted rectangles.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your goal from this question? It is a little unclear.

Comment: To have a Square [DIV] around a rectangle.